# Using pointers in functions and modifying main()

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to pass a pointer as an argument into a function that normalizes the vector pointer that was passed as an argument.

Here are the functions:

```
float norm(Vector *v) {
    float len;
    len = sqrt(pow(v->x, 2.0) + pow(v->y, 2.0) + pow(v->z, 2.0));
    return len;
}

Vector normalize(Vector *vec){
  Vector normVec;
  //calls norm function which also takes a pointer of vector type as argument
  float norm = norm(&vec);

  normVec.x = vec->x/norm;
  normVec.y = vec->y/norm;
  normVec.z = vec->z/norm;

  return normVec;
}
```

I get this error:
error: called object ‘norm’ is not a function or function pointer.
How can I get this function running smoothly?

Comment: The right place to get a thorough explanation of pointers is a good book. You can get an answer to a specific question here if you narrow it down some. Put together a [mcve] and let's figure out the first step.

Comment: regarding: `float norm = norm(&vec);`  using a variable name as a function name (in C) is very poor programming and 'usually' will cause the compiler to output a message.  Note: this question is tagged as 'c'.  and C has no type named 'Vector'  so, how is 'Vector' defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your `float norm` variable shadows the `norm()` function.
Name one of them something else.

---

Also, `vec` is already a pointer, no need to take its address (`&vec`) when you pass it to `norm()`

Comment: If I were in my main() function and I was trying to call my norm() function, would it go something like this? norm(&vecx) where vecx is a vector object.

Comment: @cap Yes exactly